zsh completion - ignore executable files with no dot in the name
I am trying to ignore files that are executable and have no dot in them, because when I am coding in C I don't want to open the binary executable files with neovim. Here is what I am trying to achieve:
ls -1

TODO.md
doc
jdsifqlwe.sh
own_os         <-- ignore this file here, because it is an exetuable && has no dot in the name
own_os.c


I have read the Completion-System - Standard Styles section and found file-patterns ignore-patterns, but I can't get it right. I don't know why this isn't working:
zstyle ':completion:*:*:nvim:*' ignored-patterns '^*.*(*)'

Because this is getting the right file:
ls -ld ^*.*(*)

Also this works:
ls -1 *(^*) *.*(*)

But I couldn't figure out a way to do multiple glob-patterns for file-patterns, because when I do the following, it doesn't work because the secondary argument is only if the first fails:
zstyle ':completion:*:*:nvim:*' file-patterns '*(^*)' '*.*(*)'



Command to recreate the directory:
mkdir -p ./BogTest/doc && \
cd ./BogTest && \
touch TODO.md jqsifqlwe.sh own_os own_os.c && \
chmod +x own_os jqsifqlwe.sh


ignored-patterns is used by the generic completion code, not by the file completion code. It's a text pattern, not a file glob. So you can't use a glob qualifier (the syntax isn't recognized, and the code that consumes this setting doesn't know about file metadata anyway). Look at file-patterns instead.

@Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' You are awesome! You have helped me quiet a few times on this site and you did it again. While I was trying to explain to you why the file-patterns didn't work while I was doing them, I figured out that I was just stupid haha. Updated my Question and answered why it didn't work. If you want you can clone my answer, then I am gonna delete mine and upvote and accept yours :)

The solution is to put both glob patterns for file-patterns into the same string.
From this:
zstyle ':completion:*:*:nvim:*' file-patterns '*(^*)' '*.*(*)'

To this:
zstyle ':completion:*:*:nvim:*' file-patterns '*(^*) *.*(*)'


Thanks to @Gilles 'SO- stop being evil' , he pointed me into the right direction :)

As @Gilles said, ignored-patterns matches strings against patterns, it's used for any completion, not just file ones. It is not a glob, something that expands to list of files, so you can't use glob qualifiers there.
For that you can use the file-patterns style which is queried by the _files completion utility function used by most completion functions that complete files, including vim/nvim's.
Now, when you add something to ignored-patterns, it is not removed for good from the possible completions. The default completer style has:
zstyle ':completion:*' completer _complete _ignored

Though one usually wants to add more (and compinstall will help you with that) such as:
zstyle ':completion:*' completer _expand _complete _ignored _correct _approximate _prefix

For the completion to do also expansion, correction, etc.
With:
zstyle ':completion:*' completer _complete _ignored

If you enter nvim foTab, and you have foo* in ignored-patterns, and there are foobar and foolish files but no other foanythingelse file in the directory, _complete will yield nothing and then we fall back to the _ignored completer which reinstates the ignored ones.
If you do:
zstyle ':completion:*:*:nvim:*' file-patterns '*(^*) *.*(*)'

Then those extension-less executables will no longer be offered by _complete, but they won't be offered by _ignored either, so the day you want to edit a script-with-a-rather-long-name-and-no-dot, you won't be able to complete it.
What you could do instead is define:
zstyle ':completion:*' completer _complete:-custom _complete _ignored

Where the _complete completer is included twice, but the first time, the completer part of the completion context will be complete-custom instead of complete.
Then, if you have:
zstyle ':completion:*:*-custom:nvim:*' file-patterns '*(^*) *.*(*)'

Instead of:
zstyle ':completion:*:*:nvim:*' file-patterns '*(^*) *.*(*)'

Then that file-patterns will be honoured by the first _complete, but not the second, so those dotless executables will be completed only if there's no other possible completion.
